SwiftUI @State vs @Binding vs @Bindable in ParentView and ChildView
i use @Observable
@Observable
class TextClass {
    var text: String = ""
}

@State

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: TextClass = .init()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(text.text)
            Button("upup") {
                text.text += "1"
            }
        }
        Form {
            ChildView(text: text)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {

    @State var text: TextClass

    var body: some View {
        Text (text.text)
        Button("upup Child") {
            text.text += "2"
        }
    }
}

@Binding

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: TextClass = .init()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(text.text)
            Button("upup") {
                text.text += "1"
            }
        }
        Form {
            ChildView(text: $text)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {

    @Binding var text: TextClass

    var body: some View {
        Text (text.text)
        Button("upup Child") {
            text.text += "2"
        }
    }
}

@Bindable

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: TextClass = .init()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(text.text)
            Button("upup") {
                text.text += "1"
            }
        }
        Form {
            ChildView(text: text)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {

    @Bindable var text: TextClass

    var body: some View {
        Text (text.text)
        Button("upup Child") {
            text.text += "2"
        }
    }
}

What are the differences between @State, @Binding, and @Bindable, all of which function similarly for bidirectional binding? Which one should I use?
I'm curious about the differences between the three.
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................


@State concept:


Two-way binding (property <-> view)
And @State is a keyword implemented as a Property wrapper and is intended to display the state of the view (with @Binding).
It means that the view will automatically change when this property changes, if you declare a property with this keyword and enter this keyword into the view (with @Binding).


@Bindable concept:


For Swift's primary types, you can declare them as @State and use them as in your example above, but if you define a new model as a class type and want this model to be automatically bound to the view like @State, this is the keyword to use (as in your example).

